# Getting Started With Javascript Programming Environment/IDE etc

Tags: javascript

I am an experienced programmer , but quite new to programming Javascript.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Downloaded Dreamweaver (Trial Version Expired).
2. Installed NotePad++ (This is what I am currently using to edit the HTML5, and Javascript).
3. Downloaded JetBrainsIDE 7.3
4. Downloaded IntellijIDE.
5. Downloaded Aptana Studio (Seems like there is a bit of a learning curve here. For example its not immediately clear how to run an html file that is not called index.html.  I imported some files into a project but only index.html would run. Also running the app just fires up the browser and hides the ide.  I realize maybe there are some setting for this, but again, I am not looking to learn an IDE if I don't have to.

So what am I doing now?  Opening and closing .js, and .html files with notepad++, then reloading the html page in the browser after I make a change.  I suspect that there is a more effective Javascript Ninja way to setup the environment.

Comment: No, there really isn't. The most "ninja" way is a text editor and a browser. You don't need an IDE. Drop DreamWeaver, nobody who knows what they're doing would touch it. That said, this question is completely subjective and a poor fit for Stack Overflow. Even more so since you're literally asking for the "ninja" way of doing something. The Ninja way would be to throw out your computer and go kill somebody with a sword, so, have fun with that.

Comment: You don't need to close notepad++ before reloading the browser - simply saving should be fine. In terms of editors, I find Notepad++ great for my needs.

Comment: Do you only need to develop html and javascript? For that only notepad++ is enough.

Comment: check out sublimetext2 my text editor of choice going on a year @ 70hrs a week. Much better than notepadd++ imo.

Comment: I'm going to conditionally disagree with the assertion from @meagar that you don't need an IDE. You don't need an IDE for small projects, which is likely your case. You *definitely* want an IDE or at least a feature-heavy text editor like Sublime for large JavaScript projects (for instance, I work on a thick-client JavaScript app, and IntelliJ is rather nice for developing that).

Comment: How about Firefox vs. Chrome.  I noticed that with Chrome you cannot edit .html files at all. I was able to edit a .js file and saw it was edited but saving it from chrome did not change the file.  Wondering what the purpose is of the sources tab in the Chrome developer tools. When would one edit a file here?  Why does it not save off?  Is this just for debugging?

Comment: Of course it's "just" for debugging.

Comment: @ajp15243 Depends on what you mean by "IDE". I work on plausably the largest Rails app in existence, of which a *massive* Backbone app is a small part. I work exclusively in Vim and Chrome. Is that an "IDE"?

Comment: @MoreQuestionsThanAnswers Firefox vs Chrome? Ok, now we're getting **super** subjective. Soliciting opinion is expressly what Stack Overflow is *not* for.

Comment: @meagar I would consider a sufficiently customized, even mod/plugin-augmented, vim as a "feature-heavy text editor". It doesn't have to have a GUI to be feature-rich, and I think you'd agree given your usage of vim :).

Comment: If you're looking for something totally different: http://www.lighttable.com/

Comment: I just bought a book called Javacript Ninja, but it was all code and nothing really about environment.

Comment: @ajp15243 Stock Vim under OSX.

Comment: @MoreQuestionsThanAnswers Avoid anything with "Ninja" in the title. Anything that says it'll make you a "ninja" in anything is pretty much crap.

Comment: @meagar It's still vim. Way better than Notepad++ IMO. (You haven't edited .vimrc at all??)

Comment: I've been using NotePad++ for a while, and I have not seen a way to have a tree view on the left side.  All my files show up as new tabs.  I think if there is a way to setup NotePad++ with treeview, showing directory structures it would be way better. I think this is one of the main reasons I started looking around for an IDE.  I just don't like seeing all the files showing up like an expanding menu. Most IDE's default to a treeview, but Notepad++ is truly like notepad in having no notion of directories.

Comment: I'm looking at SublimeText and I have to say this looks like something between and IDE and NotePad++. Maybe this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Matt Ball lighttable.com looks interesting.  I agree with the premise about the file abstractions.  And yes, its way time that IDE's/Editors kept pace with the level of innovation in other areas.

Comment: Notepad++ had a tree view last time I used it, and I don’t think it was taken out. Look harder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have installed a lot of things, but it will be easier if just use the notepad++ and a browser other than IE ... and then post problem regarding errors in coding which you may have or question that you may have in your mind..
you can also use sublime text 2... its much like winrar, a trial license that appears not to expire.

Comment: I'm also looking at sublime text and I think this is what I am looking for. Instead of just opening up files, you can open up a whole folder. goto anything is well placed and quick.  This is an amazing cross between and editor and an IDE.

Comment: yup, its nice and customizable.. there are a lot of .py scripts , u can have your own scripts, some tutorials can help you.

Comment: Another cool thing about Sublimb Text is that it effectively resizes the javascript/html as the window is resized. This is very important if want to keep more than one multiple applications on screen at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I write my client-side code using essentially a text editor and do all testing in a browser. Actually, I do my testing in multiple browsers because no two browser behaves the same.

Modern browsers usually provide "developer tools" which allow you to inspect/modify the DOM, play with the javascript console, put breakpoints, etc.

I have my text editor open on the side, and whenever I want to test my page I just save the contents and refresh the browser.

Comment: Yes, I need to learn more about the developer tools out there, and how to effectively use the debugger is the next thing I am going to do.  NotePad++ seems like a good editor, but as a new user, Sublime Text is just what I am looking for. Easy to edit, easy to resize the screen, jump to code etc.  Notepadd++ no doubt as some of these features too, but it would take me a while to learn how to use these. Actuallly I've been using Notepad for a while and I still don't know how to do the things that I can immediately do out of the box with Sublime Text. Seems like a real time saver.